# Finding a cheap houseboat accommodation in Alleppey

Tags: budget, india, accommodation

We are heading to Alleppey (Kerala, India) in two days and we are looking for cheap accommodation in houseboats through Internet. Our budget is very reduced and we would like to stay overnight in a houseboat (not only the day trip).

(Of course, we are not looking for luxury or even high standard, we are sleeping in hotels bellow 400 rupees).

What are our options? Which is a typical price for a houseboat? Does it depend on the season? Is possible to bargain with the houseboat owner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm from Tamil Nadu, India which is very near Kerala. I went to Kerala many times especially Alleppey. Its a very nice place to visit, really it's a Godzone and in answering your question I suggest you to see this page [Cheap houseboat in alleppey](http://www.cosytours.com/php/one-bedroom-kerala-houseboat-rates.php?hidDisp=1). They are very cheap, i hope :)

Comment: Welcome, but that link is just a google search result?

Comment: Sorry, i just edited the link now. Thanks for notifying me about the old link.

Comment: Sorry to say this. I haven’t stayed on that houseboat. I send this link by asking one of my friends. He only suggested this link and it’s not possible to ask him about photos of his trip. That’s why I mentioned that “They are very cheap, i hope :)”. You just go through that page and see the rates. If it’s OK means contact them otherwise Google “cheap houseboat in alleppey” and find a best one.

Comment: Thanks, a bit late for me, but may be useful for others...